# What would the Target Name for open.window be for tabpage_1?

Tags: javascript, tabs, targets

The code I show below is just sample, non working, to see if you can help with target naming conventions. I just can't seem 
to understand how you name the target. The actual code nicely creates a tabset on the page and all I'm trying to do is have 
the click event on a given tab open the URL desired in the tabpage corresponding to the tab selected. It seems like it would 
be so simple, but nothing I've tried for a target(including _parent, _self etc.) works and I can't find any examples of how 
naming conventions work for specific target locations in a document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Networks</title>
  <script>
    function open_tp1()
        {
      window.open("http://www.ficticious1.com","#tabpage_1") //What is the target name to use insead of #tabpage_1
    }
    function open_tp2()
    {
      window.open("http://www.ficticious2.com","#tabpage_2") //What is the target name to use insead of #tabpage_2
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="tabs-soc.js"></script>
  <form id="form1" name="form1">
    <div id="wrapper" style="width: 934px">
      <div id="tabContainer" style="width: 903px">
        <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
          <li id="tabHeader_1">
          <img src="image1.png" alt="Image1"  onclick="open_tp1()"  /></li>
          <li id="tabHeader_2">
          <img src="image2.png" alt="Image2" onclick="open_tp2()" /></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="tabscontent">
          <div class="tabpage" id="tabpage_1">

          </div>
          <div class="tabpage" id="tabpage_2">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's not how `window.open` works.  You may want an iframe.

Comment: Hard to be sure what you mean by "tab". Apparently you mean "div"? A browser tab is not something that appears within an HTML page.

Answer (score 1):

You can't target an HTML element, only a frame or a window. `window.open` only allows you to target a window.

If you want to replace the content of an HTML element then you must use JavaScript to fetch the data (e.g. via [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)) and then [manipulate the DOM](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Creating_and_modifying_HTML) to insert it into the page.

Since you are using absolute URIs on different domains, you will be subject to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) so you will need to use one of the [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy) for that.

Alternatively, forget about using JavaScript and place [an `iframe`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html#edef-IFRAME) in the document. Then target that with the [`target` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html#adef-target) on a link.

Comment: Thank you for help. I have inserted an iframe named and id are I1. I have inserted an href to desired .com with target="I1". When I click on  href the bottom of screen says waiting for desired .com and then nothing is displayed anywhere. Is I1 appropriate target or does it need more like document.I1 as I said at beginning of this I can't figure out naming convention for internal locations of form. @Quentin